# Create a dataset: extract features from text documents (TF-IDF)

Tags: java, information-retrieval, feature-extraction, tf-idf

I've to create a dataset from some text files, writing them as vectors of features.

Something like this:

```
doc1: 1,0.45 6,0.001 94,0.1 ...

doc2: 3,0.5 98,0.2 ...

...
```

each position of the vector represent a word, and the score is given by something like TF-IDF.

Do you know some library/tool/whatever for this? (java is better)

Answer (score 2):

After some days i found the "perfect tool" for this: Word Vector Tool.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/wvtool/

Answer (score 0):

[mallet](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/). including TF-IDF, POS, classification.

Answer (score 0):

Sure there are many eg http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucene

**However**

I recommend that you write an basic IR system from scratch. Looking under the hood is always a great learning experience.

Comment: i know, but my time is finite and TFIDF looks pretty easy to implement

Comment: i didn't mean just the TFIDF algorithm, I meant end to end, from file parsing, indexing to searching/ranking etc.